# How to auto populate the column B of Sheet2 with the age copying from Sheet1? Sheet 1 is a master sheet which contains all students name

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets in excel (Let's assume Sheet1 and Sheet2). Sheet 1 is master sheets which contains 500 students name in column A and their age in Column B.
Sheet 2 have some students name in Column A (around 100 students) and they can be found on Sheet1.

How to auto populate the column B of Sheet2 with the age copying from Sheet1?

Is their any inbuilt excel formula available or do I have to use the VB code?

I tried with VLOOKUP but didn't succeed

```
=VLOOKUP(A1, [source_sheet]!A:B,2,false)
```

Comment: `[source_sheet]` should be `'source_sheet'`  Otherwise that formula should work.  In other words, if the `[]` vs `''` is not the issue then you will need to provide a [mcve] that shows the issue directly and the error you are getting.

Comment: Can you suggest a code

Comment: Your formula should work if you do the sheet name correctly, nothing more can be suggested without more information and test data.